# login response parse and stored in session in php,soapclient

Tags: php, session, authentication, soap-client

Hello i have project in which i am using webservices to connect to client system. I have done the connection part successfully. I have to authenticate the connection through by default username,password,dms-id. That part also i have done successfully. Now i want to put my login response details in session so that i can further code depending when the login is success. I am getting login_id and token after login is successful. I want an idea how can i take this login_id and token and put into session.I am very new to session. I just want an idea how can i put my login details(login_id, token) in session if authenticaton is successful so that i can further code. Any idea will be appreciated.

Login Request

```
$wsdl = 'http://www.schwackenet.de/awonline/de/service2/SNWebService.php?wsdl';

$options = array('trace' => true);
$params = array(
  'user' =>               utf8_encode('dessenbeck'),
  'password' =>           utf8_encode('dessenbeck'),
  'corporate_group_id' => '101',
  'dealer_number' =>      'INT31303',
  'dms_id' =>             'A13T2D19',
  'dms_image_url' =>      '', 
  'dms_keepalive_url' =>  '', 
  'dms_followup_url' =>   ''  
);

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);  
    $result = $client->Login($params);
    var_dump($result);
```

?>

Login Response

```
 object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'token' => string '974jkp024icpl6q3q9nccrgonq9dv0d1' (length=32)
      public 'login_id' => int 6102355
      public 'status' => 
      object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'success' => boolean true
      public 'code' => int 0
      public 'message' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'browserURL' => string '' (length=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simple add at the beginning of file:

```
session_start();
```

and then

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);  
$result = $client->Login($params);

if ($result) { // or if ($result->status->success) {  
    $_SESSION['login_id'] = $result->login_id;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $result->token;
}
```

to save data inside session and

```
echo $_SESSION['login_id'];
```

to display data from session

**EDIT**

I'm not a Soap expert but you probably need to run `$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);` each time, so what's the point of using session in this case? I think `$_SESSION` in this case would work simply as variable but I can be wrong

Comment: Hi Marcin thank you. Yes offcourse i can pu into session variable. But how can i get login id and token into my php variable. Its login request ,response technique in SOAP Client ..Please check the updated question

Comment: @user3844830 I've added extra info to the answer

Comment: Have i think what you have answer is correct but i am expecting something else. This is related to login response in SOAP Client. I am sorry i have updated my question bit. Can you please removed it as a answer

Comment: @user3844830 I've edited it again, you can simple use `$result->login_id` syntax